# If series converges uniformly, prove $a_n$ is the Fourier coefficient

Tags: real-analysis

Let ${p_n}$ be a sequence of orthogonal functions on $[a,b]$ If series $\sum_{n=1}^{} a_n*p_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$, prove that for each $\ n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n$ is the Fourier coefficient of $f$ (this question is in Real Analysis by Manfred Stoll)

I don't know how to start it.. please give me a hint..?

Comment: Orthogonal with respect to which inner product?

Comment: <f,g>=integral a to b f(x)g(x) dx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some $p_k$. The k'th Fourier coefficient is 
$$
\alpha_k := \langle f,p_k\rangle.
$$
Since $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n p_n$, you have
$$
\alpha_k = \langle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n p_n,p_k\rangle.
$$ 
Now you have to use the uniform convergence of the series to deduce
$$
\langle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n p_n,p_k\rangle= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle a_n p_n,p_k\rangle.
$$
The othogonality of the $p_n$'s implies that the sum on the right-hand side is $a_k$. Consequently, $\alpha_k=a_k$.